# How to import Font Family in iOS Framework

Tags: ios

I have made a framework, want to add SF San Francisco font after that I want to use that framework in another project. Any one can suggest me how to add and use it in framework.

Comment: Please add more information. Target OS, static/dynamic framework, programming language...

Comment: I want to add custom font file in iOS framework, and use this framework in another project so that custom font should be appear.

Comment: Hey Nazish... after reading your question i assume that u want to add a custom font in Xcode... u can read this tutorial this helps u a lot for adding a custom font in Xcode ....
http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: I want to add font in iOS Framework, I did it successfully but when i implement this framework in another project unable to see font as desired.